# overide default date input placeholder text

Tags: javascript

i want to overide the default input tag's date text exmple dd/mm/yyyy
i tried every thing but nothing worked

```
<style>
      .form {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style>
    <div class="form">
      <div class="form">
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="date" id="sd" />
        <input type="date" id="ed" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      var d = new Date();
      var day = d.getDate().toString();
      var month = (d.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, "0");
      var year = d.getFullYear().toString();
      var today = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
      document.getElementById("sd").defaultValue = today;
      document.getElementById("ed").value = today;
    </script>
```

1. Heading

Comment: You can't. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9519493/9898651

Comment: Just set the value on the input field